# How do you set the size of a view based NSTextAttachment?

Tags: uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit, nstextattachment, nslayoutmanager

I am attempting to make something that would make it possible to add custom `UIView` subclasses as attachments in `UITextView`. As of iOS 15, there appears to be an API that allows you to register custom "view providers" for text attachments, and I've successfully managed to get a custom view showing up in a `UITextView` using that API, however I've run into a fairly large road block. I can't figure out how to set the size of one of these text attachment views. Each of my text attachment views gets a fixed size of `{.width = 37, .height = 48}` and anything I've done to try to change that results in `UITextView`'s default rendering for when you have a plain text attachment with no image (just a "missing image" placeholder icon).

In the sample code below, I just setup a view controller that has a single text view which tries to render some text with two custom view attachments. The first attachment just gets the default size that Apple gives it. For the other one I try to set the size, and you can see how it breaks things.

Am I missing something with how to use this API? I feel like I must be otherwise this API is fairly useless? What good is embedding `UIView`'s in a text view if you can make them the right size?

### Code

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface MyViewProvider : NSTextAttachmentViewProvider

@end

@implementation MyViewProvider

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [UIView new];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

@end

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController {
    UITextView *_textView;
}

#pragma mark - Initialization

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTextAttachment registerTextAttachmentViewProviderClass:[MyViewProvider class] forFileType:@"public.data"];

    NSTextAttachment *firstAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:@"public.data"];

    NSTextAttachment *secondAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:@"public.data"];
    secondAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [NSMutableAttributedString new];
    [string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is the 1st attachment: "]];
    [string appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:firstAttachment]];

    [string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\nThis is the 2nd attachment: "]];
    [string appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:secondAttachment]];

    _textView = [UITextView new];
    _textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    _textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    _textView.attributedText = string;
    [self.view addSubview:_textView];
}

#pragma mark - Layout

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    _textView.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 20, 60);
}

@end
```

### Result

[image: Result of running code sample. There are 2 text attachments, but one has failed to render after giving it a custom size.]